# Cytoscape.js: Needed linear layout

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use cytoscape.js to create network diagram. There are couple of layout which will design nodes and links from upward to downward. One of them is "dagre" layout. But, what I want is do display the same layout from left to right. But I have no luck to find such option.

Is there a way I can achieve this.
I am sharing an image url.
http://share.pho.to/9M6Sa .
It is the combination of two images **A)** What I am getting using "dagre" layout **B)** What I needed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not an expert on cytoscape, but a colleague of mine used it recently. Maybe you could write a function to exchange the ``x`` and ``y`` of each node and call it in the ``ready``.

Comment: thanks @Chop. Your suggestion and maxkfranz code solved my problem....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chop's suggestion is a good one, especially since many layouts are just wrappers external libraries like Dagre.  An example of his suggestion in practice:

```
cy.one('layoutstop', function(){
  cy.nodes.positions(function(n){
    var pos = n.position();
    return { x: pos.y, y: pos.x };
  });

  cy.fit(); // fit to new node positions
}).layout({ /* my options... */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
        container : document.getElementById('cy'),

```
    boxSelectionEnabled : true,
    autounselectify : true,

    layout : {
        name: 'dagre',
        rankDir: 'LR' // this is left to right , dagre options(rankDir)
    },
```